# How to set root to devise sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have 3 separate devise_for:

```
  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :applicants, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }
  devise_for :parents
```

The following does not work for me:

```
devise_scope :user do
  root to: "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

I also tried:

```
devise_scope :applicants do
      root to: "devise/sessions#new"
    end
```

I want to set my root page to become the devise sign in for applicants. How do I go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding removing the s in applicants.

```
devise_scope :applicant do
  root to: "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

Worked for me. Thanks